# how to get the date in my database from my select date in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to figure out how to get and insert the date in my database using the select button in my view : `<%= select_date Date.today, :date %>`

and in the migration I have a `:date` coloumn.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the way that you have it you would have to set this explicitly

```
Date.civil(params[:date][:year].to_i, params[:date][:month].to_i, params[:date][:day].to_i)
```

to get the date.

However, an easier way to do this would be to change the select.

```
<%= select_date :model, :date %>
```

or

```
<%= f.select_date :date %>
```

depending on how you are expressing the form.

Then just add a `before_create` method to the model to set the current date:

```
before_create :start_with_todays_date

def start_with_todays_date
    self.date = Date.today
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read the section **2. Dealing with Model Objects** of [the form helpers guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) or at least the [ruby on rails starting guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to figure out how to build a simple model and write controller and view (include new/edit views which contains form) for it.